# SwiftUI: different animations for transition and animatable modifiers

Tags: animation, swiftui

I'd like to have an animation on a view's transition (when it's inserted/removed in the view hierarchy) and a *different* animation on some animatable modifier.

In this example, an *easeInOut* animation for the `.transition`, and a *spring* animation for the `.rotationEffect` modifier.

**Expected outcome:** `.easeInOut` animation applies to the transition, and the `.spring` animation applies to the rotation

**Actual outcome:** the `.spring` animation applies to the transition too :-(

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var visible = false
    @State var rotated = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            if self.visible {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 50)
                    .rotationEffect(self.rotated ? .degrees(90) : .zero)
                    .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.30, blendDuration: 1))
                    .transition(.offset(x: -200, y: 0))
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {
                self.visible.toggle()
            }, label: { Text("[Visible]") })

            Button(action: {
                self.rotated.toggle()
            }, label: { Text("[Rotate]") })
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MyView())

struct Contents_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the `.spring` animation only apply to the rotation, add `value: self.rotated` to the `.animation` modifier:

```
.animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.30, blendDuration: 1), value: self.rotated)
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thank-you @vacawama - but it does feel weird that we need to do that.